# How do I run my api.ai agent on my Google Home Device?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I know this question has been asked before, but the provided answers are not resolving my issue.

I have created a Google Home Agent using the API.AI console. The purpose of my agent is to turn on/off lighting in my house (I have direct access to the "lighting API" to make this work). I have built the agent, developed/tested a Webhook for fulfillment, and configured the 'Actions on Google' on the Integrations tab. I have tested the agent locally in the console and can successfully invoke my agent via the Web Simulator. Everything works like a champ!

Except... When I ask my Google Home device to "talk to my [agent name]", it says, "...I don't understand.." According to everything I have read, when an agent is "set to preview" (and I can invoke it via the web simulator), it should be automagically available to my Google Home Device. Alas, it is not.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

(I am using the same google account to access all the bits. If it matters, I am using a "Google for Business" account).

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved... I feel a bit foolish.

It turns out that with all my testing, the one bit I didn't test via voice, was my invocation name. After testing the invocation name via voice in the web simulator, I discovered that Google could not resolve my invocation name correctly. Changing the invocation name to something phonetically distinct solved the problem. Everything works now!

Take-away: Make sure that when you are testing via the web simulator, you fully test both your intents and your invocation, via voice commands. I was trying to spare my office mates by typing in my commands. Also, make sure your invocation name is consistently resolvable by Google Home.

Comment: We discovered this as well. GoogleHome is super finicky about the invocation word which makes development on it particularly frustrating. Alexa works almost always in my testing.